# SQL query for adding up columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

```
| ORDERID | subtotal | 
--------------------
|  1000   |   50  |    

|  1000   |   100 |

|  1001   |   75  |
```

Need a query that sum up all the prices when the orderid is 1000 and return 150.
I've tried sum function with where clause but its not working.
Here is my code:

```
public double findTotalSubtotal(String order_id) {
     double sum = 0 ;
     PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        ps = connect.prepareStatement("select sum(subtotal) from order where ORDERID = ?");

     ps.setString(1,order_id);
     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
     while (rs.next()) {
          int c = rs.getInt(1);
          sum = sum + c;
        }
     }catch(Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }

    return sum;

}
```

Any my error:
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
    your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order where 
    ORDERID = '1000'' at line 1

Comment: Hint:  `SUM()` (and `WHERE`)

Comment: "I've tried sum".  So where's the query???

Comment: I just edited the post, can you read it again please.. thx

Comment: @Michael See my updated answer.  The issue is that you have a table named `order`, which is a SQL keyword.  It would be like having a variable in Java named `for`.  Fortunately, you can surround the table name with square brackets to force SQL to treat it like a table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edited to include actual table name.*

With the additional info of what your table name is, I can see what the problem is.  "order" is a SQL keyword, so you can't use it as-is as a table name in a query.  You have to surround it with <s>square brackets</s> backtics (because MariaDB):

```
select sum(price) from `order` where ORDERID = 1000
```

This assumes that the price is stored as a numerical type.  Normally that's a pretty safe assumption, but if you're storing it as a VARCHAR, this won't work (and you should probably change the table structure to use a more appropriate type).

Comment: Still getting the same error even i surrounded it with  [ ]

Comment: @Michael Try my modified answer.  Looks like MariaDB uses quotes instead of square backets.  I *think* it expects backtics, but that's just based on skimming some of their docs.